# How to add Qt private module's libs?

Tags: qt, qt5, qtplugin

I am trying to use a `xmlpatterns-private`. I could get the headers by adding `qt += xmlpatterns-private`. But when I compile it gives the error:

> undefined reference to `QPatternist::XsdSchemaResolver::~XsdSchemaResolver()'

So it supposes means that header was found but the lib didn't install my Qt environment. How to install or adding such a private module into Qt instead of compiling the whole Qt source? I'm guessing that I shall pull the `xmlpatterns` source and compile it, put it into some folder... In other words how to perform the installation of the private module.

What I tried:

1. Download Qt 5.13 source code
2. Open `qtxmlpatterns.pro` in QtCreator
3. Add `CONFIG+=xml-schema` in `qtxmlpatterns.pro`
4. Build
5. Go to build folder and run `mingw32-make install`
6. Rebuild my project, but gives the same error...

Update:

the function cannot be found is because Qt didn't export it using `Q_XMLPATTERNS_EXPORT`.

So I import the whole `xmlpatterns` source into my project instead of `qt += xmlpatterns-private`. the cpp already part of the project why the function still cannot be found.

> error: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN12QXmlNamePoolC1Ev'

The whole project: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1B2YEz1iUHdbZ-F3ukBRpjZ9eP012Jkez?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

```
#ifndef Q_XMLPATTERNS_EXPORT
#  ifndef QT_STATIC
#    if defined(QT_BUILD_XMLPATTERNS_LIB)
#      define Q_XMLPATTERNS_EXPORT Q_DECL_EXPORT
#    else
#      define Q_XMLPATTERNS_EXPORT Q_DECL_IMPORT
#    endif
#  else
#    define Q_XMLPATTERNS_EXPORT
#  endif
#endif
...
#  ifdef Q_OS_WIN
#    define Q_DECL_EXPORT     __declspec(dllexport)
#    define Q_DECL_IMPORT     __declspec(dllimport)
...
```

> undefined reference to
>   `QPatternist::XsdSchemaResolver::~XsdSchemaResolver()'

this is because of the `XsdSchema...` didn't `__declspec(dllexport)`.
there are many private Qt classes is invisible API.
so cannot find the reference if I use as lib.
If I modify all the necessary class with export keywords. it supposes to solve the error.
(didn't confirm)

instead of using the lib, I import the whole source code into the project.
it gives

> error: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN12QXmlNamePoolC1Ev'

because of the class having `__declspec(dllimport)` it tells to find the reference in the lib which shall be imported. But now the private classes actually is part of source code(of course, it's undefined I didn't import it).
Remove the `__declspec(dllimport)` solves it(confirmed, build successed).